# d3js: adding multiple colors to each bars based on variables using if condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, d3.js

I created a horizontal bar chart.

The width of each bar is based on object variable **volume**. Later I realized I need to make each bar a stack bar instead, the 2 categories object variables are **vol1** & **vol2**, where **vol1** + **vol2** = **volume**.

I was wondering if there is a direct way to assign **2 colors** to *each bar* based on **vol1** & **vol2** values instead of the usual stacked bar method where you need to (a) arrange data in arrays based on their categories, (b) define **x, y, y0** (c) assign different colors to each array bars.

data structure:

```
var data = [
{ "merchant": "A",
  "volume": 100,
  "vol1": 48,
  "vol2": 52
},
{...},
{...}
];
```

The specific code to draw the chart is:

```
    var bar = d3.select(".mainGroup").selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data_merchantTop100Vol);

    bar.attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", d => y(d.merchant))
        .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
        .transition().duration(50)
        .attr("width", d => x(d.volume));

    bar.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", d => y(d.merchant))
        .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
        .transition().duration(50)
        .attr("width", d => x(d.volume))
        // THIS PART IS TO FILL 2 COLORS TO THE 2 SECTIONS OF EACH BAR
        // .style("fill", function(d) {
        //     if(d.Vol1) { return "blue"}
        //     else if (d.vol2) { return "red"};
        // })
```

In short, I want to create a horizontal stacked bar using if-condition coloring method instead of typical stacked bar method. Idea inspiration: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/select-items-with-if-statement-in-d3js.html

Current horizontal bar chart:
[image]

Desired outcome:
[image]

Comment: So, you want to end up with a single `rect` that is filled based on the the percentage of values `vol1` and `vol2`?  Or you want two `rect` where each bar is filled to a color?

Comment: A single `rect` that is filled based on the % of values `vol1` and `vol2`. It will be typical stacked bar method if I have 2 `rect`. :)

Comment: It's doable, if you really want it, but @mpbastos is correct below.  Much simpler to use two rects.

Comment: Just for learning purpose, how can it be done?

Comment: Added single bar answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to fill the rectangles with [gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) using the right percentages but this would over complicate the solution. The easiest way would be using one rectangle for each color. You do not need to rearrange the data for this:

```
// Vol1 bars
    bar.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", d => y(d.merchant))
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
        .transition().duration(50)
        .attr("width", d => x(d.vol1))
    .style("fill", "blue")

// Vol2 bars
    bar.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", d => x(d.vol1))
        .attr("y", d => y(d.merchant))
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
        .transition().duration(50)
        .attr("width", d => x(d.vol2))
    .style("fill", "red")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really want do this with a single bar, you'd have to set up custom gradients that could split the color on a percentage:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    var data = [{
      volume: Math.random() * 400,
      vol1: Math.random() * 400,
      vol2: Math.random() * 400
    }, {
      volume: Math.random() * 400,
      vol1: Math.random() * 400,
      vol2: Math.random() * 400
    }, {
      volume: Math.random() * 400,
      vol1: Math.random() * 400,
      vol2: Math.random() * 400
    }, {
      volume: Math.random() * 400,
      vol1: Math.random() * 400,
      vol2: Math.random() * 400
    }];

    var height = 400,
      width = 600,
      color1 = "orange",
      color2 = "steelblue",
      barHeight = 20;

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

    var defs = svg.append("defs");

    var g = svg.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")

    g.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return d.volume
      })
      .attr("height", barHeight)
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * (barHeight + 5);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {

        var p = (d.vol1 / (d.vol1 + d.vol2)) * 100,
          grad = defs.append("linearGradient")
          .attr("id", "grad_" + i);

        grad.append("stop")
          .attr("offset", "0%")
          .attr("stop-color", color1);
        grad.append("stop")
          .attr("offset", (p) + "%")
          .attr("stop-color", color1);
        grad.append("stop")
          .attr("offset", (p) + "%")
          .attr("stop-color", color2);
        grad.append("stop")
          .attr("offset", "100%")
          .attr("stop-color", color2);

        return "url(#grad_" + i + ")";
      });
      
    g.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.volume + 12
      })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return (i * (barHeight + 5)) + 13;
      })
      .text(function(d){
        var p1 = (d.vol1 / (d.vol1 + d.vol2)) * 100,
            p2 = (d.vol2 / (d.vol1 + d.vol2)) * 100;
        
        return Math.round(p1) + "% and " + Math.round(p2) + "%";
      })
      .style("stroke", "none")
      .style("fill", "black")
      .style("font-family", "arial")
      .style("font-size", "12px");
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```